# Stored procedure to replace null's in FK on fact table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, etl

I have built a fact table in a staging area, where some of the FK (the BK from dimensions) are NULL.

During the ETL in SSIS, I have used a derived column to replace all NULL's with the value "-1".

The problem is that I have 15 columns and it takes a long time to populate the entire table.

Is there a stored procedure that I can use to avoid this? Or any other method that reduces this time?

Comment: Your existing code would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it doing the following stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Inferred_FACT_TABLE] 
    
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[FACT_STG_cenas]
        SET [FK_Alpha] = -1
        WHERE [FK_Alpha] IS NULL

        UPDATE [dbo].[FACT_STG_cenas]
        SET [FK_Bravo] = -1
        WHERE [FK_Bravo] IS NULL

        UPDATE [dbo].[FACT_STG_cenas]
        SET [FK_Lima] = -1
        WHERE [FK_Lima] IS NULL

        UPDATE [dbo].[FACT_STG_cenas]
        SET [FK_Charlie] = -1
        WHERE [FK_Charlie] IS NULL

        UPDATE [dbo].[FACT_STG_cenas]
        SET [FK_Mike] = -1
        WHERE [FK_Mike] IS NULL

    
    END
END
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).